# Hive script issue

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am running the following shell script,

```
#!/bin/bash
HADOOP_HOME='/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2'
HIVE_HOME='/home/hadoop/hive-0.8.0'

echo -e '1\x01foo' > /tmp/a.txt
echo -e '2\x01bar' >> /tmp/a.txt

HADOOP_CORE={{ls $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar}}
CLASSPATH=.:$HADOOP_CORE:$HIVE_HOME/conf

for i in ${HIVE_HOME}/lib/*.jar ; do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
done

java -cp $CLASSPATH HiveJdbcClient
```

In this code every variable is set properly. I have written code as per instructions given [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-JDBCClientSampleCode). My hive version is 0.8.0. 
When I run my code it gives me the following error,

```
./test.sh
./test.sh: line 8: /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar}}: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to localhost:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
        at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:22)
```

Can anyone please explain me what this error means?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing indicates that Java could not connect to the port with the JDBC server.

You should start it by following the [instructions on the HiveServer wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer). Something like:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service hiveserver
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

code Banger, here tricky thing is that Hive was not running in the background at all.

Check it is running.

First export the hive port, then start the hive.

$ export HIVE_PORT=10000

Good luck!